# Error while accessing my gmail account in Ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, syslinux

I was trying to access my Gmail account which is also my gnome account in Linux but it was showing this message

[image]

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Please tell me why do we get this...

Comment: OP, I suggest not including your email address for everyone to see. You can black it out and then flag this question for mod attention if you want your email removed from the revisions list.

Comment: You don't seem to have an active internet connection on the system

Comment: @Kulfy , As soon as start the internet It started thanks

Comment: @someone thanks for editing my question

Comment: No problem, in future be sure that you don't share these details on internet (if you don't want spam emails) :)